# Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted + Trigger Error SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, trigger

This trigger will update `Is_Confidential_or_VIP` column to 1 or 0 based on the text inserted or updated into `ConfidentialRegistrationFlag` and `VIPType` columns :

```
create trigger [dbo].[Is_Confidential_or_VIP]
on  [EDB].[dbo].[Patient_Info]
after update,insert 
AS
BEGIN
    declare @type1 nvarchar(max)
    declare @type2 nvarchar(max)

    (select @type1 = ConfidentialRegistrationFlag from inserted)
    (select  @type2 = VIPType from inserted)

    declare @flag int

    if (@type2 like 'MDP-A' or @type2 like 'MDP-B' or @type1= 'confidential')
       set @flag= 1
    else 
       set @flag= 0

    update EDB.dbo.Patient_Info
    set Is_Confidential_or_VIP = @flag
    where EPN = (select EPN from inserted)
 END
```

I have a problem when enabling this trigger cannot insert data and error msg:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value

Comment: Your trigger has **MAJOR FLAW** in that you seem to assume it'll be called **once per row** - that is **not** the case. The trigger will fire **once per statement**, so if your `UPDATE` statements affects 25 rows, you'll get the trigger fired **once**, but then `Inserted` and `Deleted` will each contain 25 rows. Which of those 25 rows will your code select? It's non-deterministic. You need to rewrite your trigger to take this into account!

Answer (score 3):

Actually Triggers fire once rather than multiple times if update statement modify more than one row.

Your trigger trying to update multiple rows which means Inserted table will also have more than one row and when you try to set Flag values, it return you error.

Join your `table`'s key with `Inserted`

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[Is_Confidential_or_VIP] ON [EDB].[dbo].[Patient_Info]
    AFTER UPDATE, INSERT
AS
    BEGIN

        UPDATE  patinfo
        SET     Is_Confidential_or_VIP = CASE WHEN VIPType = 'MDP-A'  --- 'Like' Replaced with '='
                                                   OR VIPType = 'MDP-B'
                                                   OR ConfidentialRegistrationFlag = 'confidential'
                                              THEN 1
                                              ELSE 0
                                         END                    
         -- select case VIPType = 'MDP-A' OR VIPType = 'MDP-B'  OR ConfidentialRegistrationFlag = 'confidential' then 1 else 1  END,*
        FROM    EDB.dbo.Patient_Info patinfo
                INNER JOIN inserted i ON patinfo.EPN = i.EPN

    END
```